# Why does property size validation induce a constructor call?

Tags: matlab

I have encountered a behaviour in Matlab that I cannot quite get my head around. I'm writing a `handle` class called `PlottingUI` which takes a `SolitonSolution` as its only input (where `SolitonSolution` is a `value` class that I have also written). It looks something like this:

```matlab
classdef PlottingUI < handle
    properties (Access = private)
        ss(1,1) SolitonSolution
        ...
    end
    methods (Access = public)
        function obj = PlottingUI(ss)
            obj.ss = ss;
            ...
        end
        ...
    end
    ...
end
```

Note especially the `(1,1)` in the properties validation block. It might seem unnecesary, but it is intended to stop the user from trying to pass, say, an array of `SolitonSolution` objects. It certainly should not hurt to have it. But now, if I attempt to instantiate a PlottingUI object with

```matlab
...
ui = PlottingUI(ss);
```

where `ss` is a previously instantiated `SolitonSolution` object, then I get an error like this:

```
Error using SolitonSolution (line 14)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in testUI (line 17)
ui = PlottingUI(ss);
```

`testUI` is just the script name. The line in `SolitonSolution` that it gets stuck on is an `narginchk` call in its constructor. The call stack at this moment is

```
SolitonSolution.SolitonSolution
testUI
Base
```

so this happens before entering the `PlottingUI` constructor.

The really weird thing is that if I remove the size specification `(1,1)` in the `PlottingUI` properties block the error disappears.

**So it seems like the size specification `(1,1)` induces a call to the `SolitonSolution` constructor (with no arguments) before calling the `PlottingUI` constructor. But why?**